# Best way to send HTTP on model after_update or after_create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

may be it's not the best question. But I'll try to explain.
I need to synchronize Model with the external service.

So there are many entry points where the model can be updated or created.
So I need to listen the after_update and after_create events.

I do not prefer to call HTTP inside the model and I'm looking for the best way to do it out of the model. (PS I know that we could use module with base.class_eval, but at the and it also is a part of the end model)

I've found https://github.com/krisleech/wisper library that implements 
Publisher/Subscriber approach. 
Is it the best way to do it?

Comment: Do you need transactional approach? If update is valid in the first system, but crashes in second one (or it's offline), should you apply update in the first system? Also, do you need immediate update in the second system? Think about updating 10k models at once, and 10k requests.

Comment: Maybe try pushing an `ActiveJob.perform_later` in your model callback, and let the Job take care of the HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

Using an ActiveRecord's callback is a very dirty way.

You should wrap your model's creation/update in a service, to avoid code duplication and encapsulate this logic.

Also, using active job to perform async the HTTP request will be a good idea.

```
class MyService
  def create(args)
    model = Model.create(args)
    ActiveJob.perform_later(model) if model.persisted?
    model
  end

  def update(model, args)
    result = model.update_attributes(args)
    ActiveJob.perform_later(model) if result
    result
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. 

You and other guys are absolutely right.
Your approach is working in the case when we have only one entry point for creation.

The problem is that the system has a lot of entry points where the model can be created or updated in the different ways and it would be great to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @VolodymyrO I'have added some update logic to the example. If updates are very different, you also can pass a block to the method and use `yield self` to get the result of save.

Comment: `model = Model.create(args)` will never by falsy. Even when validation fails, `create` returns the invalid model.

Comment: I'm going to oppose @Fede and say that callbacks are already there (in the framework) and easier to grasp for new-comers than a custom service infrastructure. As long as you don't abuse of callbacks, they are valid solutions too. That said, ActiveJob or any other way of asynchronous jobs/workers is the way to go, because external HTTP requests are going to be too slow.

Comment: @Leito haha. Thats true. I havent been programming in rails in a while. Using create and checking if was `persisted?` will work. I would rather prefer to use servicies to decoulpe that logic from the model itself, since is an external service and it shouldnt be the model responsability to know how to make an http request

Answer (score 0):

Your heart is right place making sure you keep code where it belongs. Instead of a custom service I would recommend keeping it as callbacks, but move most of the code to it's own Active Job (that way you can run it asynchronously). The way I view it, the model is in charge of persistance, hence it's the best place to "flag" when the model is changed and let someone else go and do the syncing job.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_commit :create_external, on: :create

  private

  def create_external
    CreateExternalFooJob.perform_later self
  end
end

class CreateExternalFooJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(foo)
    # Create object in external service with HTTP
  end
end
```

`after_commit` also can be triggered on `:update` and `:destroy` allowing you to keep the external service in sync.

Rails had a way to move callbacks to its own class, it was called [Observers](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers) and it was moved to its own gem after 4.0. Consider this or Services as suggested by @Fede if you are using too many callbacks.